# Initializing database failed in MySQL server 8.0.111 on windows 7 64

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create MySql Server version 8.0.11 on Windows 7 64bit , I got this :

[image]

```
Here are the logs : 

Beginning configuration step: Writing configuration file
Ended configuration step: Writing configuration file

Beginning configuration step: Updating Windows Firewall rules
Attempting to delete a Windows Firewall rule with command: netsh.exe advfirewall firewall delete rule name="Port 5050" protocol=TCP localport=5050

Deleted 2 rule(s).
Ok.


Adding a Windows Firewall rule for MySQL80 on port 5050.
Attempting to add a Windows Firewall rule with command: netsh.exe advfirewall firewall add rule name="Port 5050" protocol=TCP localport=5050 dir=in action=allow
Ok.


Successfully added the Windows Firewall rule.
Ended configuration step: Updating Windows Firewall rules

Beginning configuration step: Adjusting Windows service
Attempting to grant Network Service require filesystem permissions.
Granted permissions.
Updating existing service
Existing service updated
Ended configuration step: Adjusting Windows service

Beginning configuration step: Initializing Database
Attempting to run MySQL Server with --initialize-insecure option...
Starting process for MySQL Server 8.0.11...
Starting process with command: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe --defaults-file="C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\my.ini" --console --initialize-insecure=on...
2018-07-02T23:37:38.137575Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-011071] [Server] Unknown suffix '.' used for variable 'lower_case_table_names' (value '0.0')
2018-07-02T23:37:38.137575Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-011071] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe: Error while setting value '0.0' to 'lower_case_table_names'
2018-07-02T23:37:38.137575Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2018-07-02T23:37:38.137575Z 0 [Note] [MY-010120] [Server] Binlog end
Process for mysqld, with ID 6256, was run successfully and exited with code 1.
Failed to start process for MySQL Server 8.0.11.
Database initialization failed.
Ended configuration step: Initializing Database
```

Can't find from this log if the error is MySql error or something wrong with my windows.

Comment: [lower_case_table_names](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_lower_case_table_names) expects an integer. There's no really point in setting it to `0.0`.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález  the problem is I didn't find where and in which step did I configure this value!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved, Just uninstalled everything that belongs to myseql .. restart my pc and installed again but this time I agreed to let the installer get the latest updates .. it worked

Answer (score 0):

For me what worked was that in the installation step, instead of proceeding with the "Developer Default" in the "Choosing as Setup Type" section, I proceeded with the "Full" version. Also, note that in the "Accounts and Roles" section I did "add a user". Then everything worked out well; hope it helps someone.