# Error during MySQL Installation ("Initializing database" Failure)

Tags: mysql, installation

During the last steps of the installation of MySQL Community Server (Apply Configurations) in Windows 10, I get an error initializing the database. This is the Log :

> Beginning configuration step: Initializing database (may take a long
> time) Attempting to run MySQL Server with --initialize-insecure
> option... Starting process for MySQL Server 8.0.25... Starting process
> with command: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe
> --defaults-file="C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\my.ini" --console --initialize-insecure=on --lower-case-table-names=1... mysqld: Can't get stat of
> 'C:\Users\Public\Documents\Wondershare\CreatorTemp' (OS errno 2 - No
> such file or directory) 'NO_ZERO_DATE', 'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE' and
> 'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO' sql modes should be used with strict
> mode. They will be merged with strict mode in a future release. The
> designated data directory C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Data
> is unusable. You can remove all files that the server added to it.
> Aborting Process for mysqld, with ID 11240, was run successfully and
> exited with code 1. Failed to start process for MySQL Server 8.0.25.
> Database initialization failed. Ended configuration step: Initializing
> database (may take a long time)

What can I do to solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Initializing database failed in MySQL server 8.0.111 on windows 7 64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51138896/initializing-database-failed-in-mysql-server-8-0-111-on-windows-7-64)

Answer (score 3):

I have the same question a few months ago and then yesterday I decided to just create the directory shown in the error log similar to yours and everything works fine now.....

All I did is I opened the command prompt, change the directory by typing:  cd C:\Users\Public\Documents then enter......

After then directory has changed I then typed: mkdir Wondershare\CreatorTemp and Enter.

After I click execute in mysql installation everything works fine......

Comment: Thank you. I deleted this folder a few days ago and never thought it was the reason for my database not working...

Answer (score 1):

Delete all the files with name MySql from Program Data or Program Files in C.
Reinstall all stuff and it will solve this error.
This works for me.